# Selecting a value of <option> by AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, html

I do an interaction for options, and want it to be selected the first option

```
        <select class="form-control" 
                  name="accounts"
                  ng-model="vm.deposit.account"
                  ng-options="account.account as account.agency for account in vm.accounts"
                  required>
          </select>
```

Need is to try the type 'Selected'. I've tried to use ng-select, but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is to init your model in your controller or using ng-init

```
vm.deposit.account = vm.accounts[0].account;
```

Comment: It would be that way?

  ng-init = "vm.deposit.account = vm.accounts [0] .account"

I already tried that way and not selected

Comment: you can try it in your controller but normally ng-init should work

Comment: i try, but, not selected.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, just set

vm.deposit.account = vm.accounts[0].account;  //or whatever the active account should be